# Cannot write at specified position with StreamWriter

Tags: c#, stream

I am trying to write to a file from the beginning of that file using a `StreamWriter`, and am having a lot of difficulty. I've tried to use the `Seek(offset, origin)` method but this seems to be ignored and my code always writes to the end of my file instead. I have no idea what is going on here, the other solutions say that using `Seek` should allow me to write the file from a position that I get to choose...

Anyway, here is my code.

```
// open up access to the file
record = new StreamWriter(recordPath, false);

// write some data
record.WriteLine("1");
record.WriteLine("2");
record.WriteLine("3");

// set the cursor to the beginning of the file
record.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

// write the header into the file
foreach (var s in this.toBeRecorded)
{
    record.Write(@"=""""Channel " + s.Key + @""""",="""""""",="""""""",");
}
record.Write("\r\n");
foreach (var s in this.toBeRecorded)
{
    record.Write(@"=""Time"",=""Data"",="""""""",");
}
record.Write("\r\n");
```

I purposely want to overwrite `1`, `2`, and `3` here, but I cannot. Why?

Comment: I don't believe prepending (as opposed to appending) is a supported feature. Your best bet may be to generate what is needed to be written in a string and then append the current version of the file to that string and write the result.

Comment: Problem is, I won't know how many channels the user has decided to use until the application disconnects. I am constantly writing data on another thread until the user disconnects. I want to prepend the header stating each channel, and then the data will come underneath. @Hank that is helpful to know that this may not be a supported feature. I was going nuts here trying to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Inserting `record.Flush();` before `Seek` can solve your problem... But I don't think it is a real solution ....

Comment: @L.B I tried that, it doesn't fix my problem. Still writes to the end. Thanks though.

Comment: Although I think it is severely inefficient, you could save the current data, add it to a string, append the new data, and then overwrite the file with the new string. It just makes me cringe to suggest that if you process a large amount of data.

Comment: @StevieV Funny, since I tested it before writing my comment....

Comment: @Hank my thoughts are the same as yours. So much data coming in, and I won't know how many channels the user selected until the end so I'd really like to prepend the header.

Comment: @L.B I saw a similar solution on another question, it didn't work for me. Yeah I called `.BaseStream.Flush()` before `Seek`.

Comment: @StevieV So why exactly does it have to prepend? What is the negative of it writing like a log file?

Comment: I just want it to say Channel A ... Channel B ... Channel C ... at the top. Data is being recorded all of the time, the user can turn on/off the channels that are recording in real-time. So no way to predict exactly how many channels are used, but once the user is done with the session, I'll know exactly how many they used so I would just prepend it.

Comment: @StevieV You should learn reading comments carefully,.. I said **`record.Flush();`** not **`record.BaseStream.Flush();`** They are not equal considering some bufferings.....

Comment: @L.B Thanks, will give it a try.

Comment: @StevieV You give it a try **now**? Just comment before testing it?

Comment: @L.B I can't understand a word you are saying, but thanks for the idea. I will give it a try and let you know what the results are. Does that make sense?

Comment: @StevieV You wrote *I tried that, it doesn't fix my problem. Still writes to the end.*  **without** testing it....

Comment: @L.B that worked, thanks.

Comment: @L.B my apologies I misread your comment. I used `BaseStream.Flush()` when you indicated to use `Flush()`. Going back and doing it your exact way, everything worked! Thanks!

Comment: @StevieV I didn't say use `Flush`, I wrote `record.Flush();`

Comment: @L.B Why don't you think that it's a real solution?

Comment: Since the solution has been determined, please post an answer so others with this issue may learn a possible solution to their problem without having to read comments.

Comment: @Hank Definitely will if nobody else does. But I want to give whoever came up with it a chance to, since I did not come up with the solution.